# Camera Preview not working when i added surface view as Header of GridView | Andorid

Tags: android, gridview, android-camera, carousel, surfaceview

I have implemented Custom Camera in Android. Its working fine at first time.
I also used `FeatureCoverFlow` as Carousel view, so whenever i am gonna scroll my carousel `FeatureCoverFlow` items, the preview stopped working.

Here is my Code -

```
/*Custom camera*/

        preview = new Preview(getActivity(), (SurfaceView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
        preview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
        //preview.setBackground();
        FrameLayout mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) headerView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        mFrameLayout.addView(preview);
        mFrameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camera_icon);
        //mFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        try {
            if (_camera == null) {
                _camera = Camera.open();
                _camera.startPreview();
                System.out.println("camera null---------------------");

                preview.setCamera(_camera);


                _camera.setErrorCallback(new Camera.ErrorCallback() {

                    public void onError(int error, Camera _camera) {
                        System.out.println("setErrorCallback Called");
                        _camera.lock();
                        _camera.release();
                        _camera = Camera.open();
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (_camera != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(),
                        Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, _camera);
            preview.setCamera(_camera);
            System.out.println("camera is not null ---------------------");
        }
        /*custom camera ends here*/
```

And code of Scroll listener -

```
mCoverFlow.setOnScrollPositionListener(new FeatureCoverFlow.OnScrollPositionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolledToPosition(int position) {
                //TODO CoverFlow stopped to position


                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            /*Custom camera*/
                        try {
                            if (_camera == null) {
                                _camera = Camera.open();
                                _camera.startPreview();
                                System.out.println("camera null---------------------");


                                preview.setCamera(_camera);


                                _camera.setErrorCallback(new Camera.ErrorCallback() {

                                    public void onError(int error, Camera _camera) {
                                        System.out.println("setErrorCallback Called");
                                        _camera.lock();
                                        _camera.release();
                                        _camera = Camera.open();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                        if (_camera != null) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                                setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(),
                                        Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, _camera);
                            preview.setCamera(_camera);
                            System.out.println("camera is not null ---------------------");
                        }
        /*custom camera ends here*/

                    }
                });
}
```

**But Still its NOT working** Please help me out. I am stuck with this issue.

Many Thanks in Advance.